# Getting NaN after arithmetic operation of variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i am performing arithmetic operation on an array, that i got from response through JSON. 
but i don't know why i am getting NaN after addition.

```
var a = new Array();
var b = 0;
var c = 0;
alert(b);
for (var x = 0; x < length; x++) {
    a[x] = response.data[x]
}
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    alert('value of b: ' + b); //first time 0 than NaN
    c = a[i];
    a[i] = a[i] - b;
    chart.addSeries(response.legend + "-" + i, a[i], {
        color: colorArray[i]
    }); //performing DOJO chart functioning
    b = b + a[i];
    console.log(b);
    alert('value of a: ' + a[i]); // here  value comes NaN              
}
```

in the above code response.data represents a JSONArray that contains chart data. Here what the reason for getting NaN.

JSON:

```
{
    "legend": 5,
    "data": [
        [
            {
                "text": "June",
                "value": 6,
                "customerID": "RITL00002",
                "y": 0
            },
            {
                "‌​text": "July",
                "value": 7,
                "customerID": "RITL00002",
                "y": 0
            },
            {
                "text": "Auguest",
                "value": 8,
                "customerID": "RITL00002",
                "y": 0
            },
            {
                "text": "September",
                "value": 9,
                "customerID": "RIT‌​L00002",
                "y": 0
            },
            {
                "text": "October",
                "value": 10,
                "customerID": "RITL00002",
                "y": 41995.52
            },
            {
                "text": "November",
                "value": 11,
                "customerID": "RITL00002",
                "y": 566353.8099999999
            },
            {
                "text": "December",
                "value": 12,
                "customerID": "RITL00002",
                "y": 0
            }
        ]
    ],
    "Success": true,
    "da‌​taLength": 1
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the value of `length`?

Comment: NaN comes when one of the operator is `undefined`. Please debug and check.

Comment: can you show us the json.

Comment: without seeing your response data(JSON) its not possible to debug.

Comment: length contains JSONArray length,i.e length of data Array. and setting length value in controller class (outside jsp).

Comment: alert the value of a[0] after first for loop.

Comment: the NaN comes from `response.data` i.e. JSON. Show us your json

Comment: This all looks really hinky. Why are you copying an array to a new array in a loop, and what's this `length` you keep refering to, do you even have a variable named `length`, or did you mean `array.length`? It seems like this would be really easy if we knew what the heck you where doing, just a single loop, iterating over the array in `response.data`, and a closure and passing everyting to `chart.addSeries()`. Now it's just a mess ?

Comment: i am assigning dataLength to Length in jsp as--  var length = response.dataLength;

Comment: {"legend":5,"data":[[{"text":"June","value":6,"customerID":"RITL00002","y":0},{"text":"July","value":7,"customerID":"RITL00002","y":0},{"text":"Auguest","value":8,"customerID":"RITL00002","y":0},{"text":"September","value":9,"customerID":"RITL00002","y":0},{"text":"October","value":10,"customerID":"RITL00002","y":41996.52},{"text":"November","value":11,"customerID":"RITL00002","y":566353.8099999999},{"text":"December","value":12,"customerID":"RITL00002","y":0}]],"Success":true,"dataLength":1}

Comment: dude your json is not valid check on jsonlint.com, copy and paste your json there.

Comment: @Learning , yes i have edited the json string.

Comment: @Learning , here in first for loop i am getting array of objects. that could be the cause of getting Nan.

Comment: yup that is the actual reason of getting NAN. What is expected in a[x]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you wanted to save the values of `"y"` of data in array `"a"`

for accessing `"y"` you need to get the value of `response.data[0][x].y`.

So your final code will looks like

```
var a = new Array();
var b = 0;
var c = 0;
alert(b);
for (var x = 0; x < length; x++) {
    a[x] = response.data[0][x].y;
}
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    alert('value of b: ' + b); //first time 0 than NaN
    c = a[i];
    a[i] = a[i] - b;
    chart.addSeries(response.legend + "-" + i, a[i], {
        color: colorArray[i]
    }); //performing DOJO chart functioning
    b = b + a[i];
    console.log(b);
    alert('value of a: ' + a[i]); // here  value comes NaN              
}
```

Please let me know if you wants something else.

check fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9Lvnh/)